# How to access the URL that Acegi has stored for after the login form in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, gigya

I'm integrating Gigya with a web app running Acegi.

I have it working that the client side Gigya can authenticate an existing user and then skip the login form post and hit a controller method to inform the server securly that the user authentication has been performed by Gigya.

Using the following code in my controller I'm able to tell Acegi that the user has authenticated.

```
def user = com.playhardsports.football.web.admin.auth.User.find("from User where username=?", [UID])
def authorities = [new GrantedAuthorityImpl('ROLE_USER')] as GrantedAuthority[]
def userDetails = new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUserImpl(UID, fakePassword, true, true, true, true, authorities, user)
def authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, fakePassword, authorities)
SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication = authentication
```

The problem I'm having now is that I don't know where to redirect the user after the authentication.

A common scenario is that the user visits a protected page and Acegi redirects them to the login form.  On my login form I also have the controls for Gigya to validate the user.  Of course, meanwhile, the normal Acegi flow would be after login to redirect back to the original protected page.

So I'm looking for how to access that url, and if there was no url, because the person went straight to login, then how to find the default url that Acegi has configured.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the `SavedRequest` from the session:

```
import org.springframework.security.ui.savedrequest.SavedRequest
import org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter as APF

def savedRequest = session[APF.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY]
String originalUrl = savedRequest?.fullRequestUrl ?: '/'
```